# How to avoid gaps due to missing values in matplot in R?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a function that uses `matplot` to plot some data. Data structure is like this:

```
test = data.frame(x = 1:10, a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
matplot(test[,-1])
matlines(test[,1], test[,-1])
```

So far so good. However, if there are missing values in the data set, then there are gaps in the resulting plot, and I would like to avoid those by connecting the edges of the gaps.

```
test$a[3:4] = NA
test$b[7] = NA
matplot(test[,-1])
matlines(test[,1], test[,-1])
```

[image]

In the real situation this is inside a function, the dimension of the matrix is bigger and the number of rows, columns and the position of the non-overlapping missing values may change between different calls, so I'd like to find a solution that could handle this in a flexible way. I also need to use `matlines`

I was thinking maybe filling in the gaps with intrapolated data, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but anyway. My advice in a situation like this is, don't try to cover the gaps. Let the reader know that there were missing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this exact situation today, but I didn't want to interpolate values - I just wanted the lines to "span the gaps", so to speak. I came up with a solution that, in my opinion, is more elegant than interpolating, so I thought I'd post it even though the question is rather old.

The problem causing the gaps is that there are `NA`s between consecutive values. So my solution is to 'shift' the column values so that there are no `NA` gaps. For example, a column consisting of `c(1,2,NA,NA,5)` would become `c(1,2,5,NA,NA)`. I do this with a function called `shift_vec_na()` in an `apply()` loop. The x values also need to be adjusted, so we can make the x values into a matrix using the same principle, but using the columns of the y matrix to determine which values to shift.

Here's the code for the functions:

```
# x -> vector
# bool -> boolean vector; must be same length as x. The values of x where bool 
#   is TRUE will be 'shifted' to the front of the vector, and the back of the
#   vector will be all NA (i.e. the number of NAs in the resulting vector is
#   sum(!bool))
# returns the 'shifted' vector (will be the same length as x)
shift_vec_na <- function(x, bool){
  n <- sum(bool)
  if(n < length(x)){
    x[1:n] <- x[bool]
    x[(n + 1):length(x)] <- NA
  } 
  return(x)
}

# x -> vector
# y -> matrix, where nrow(y) == length(x)
# returns a list of two elements ('x' and 'y') that contain the 'adjusted'
# values that can be used with 'matplot()'
adj_data_matplot <- function(x, y){
  y2 <- apply(y, 2, function(col_i){
    return(shift_vec_na(col_i, !is.na(col_i)))
  })
  
  x2 <- apply(y, 2, function(col_i){
    return(shift_vec_na(x, !is.na(col_i)))
  })
  return(list(x = x2, y = y2))
}
```

Then, using the sample data:

```
test <- data.frame(x = 1:10, a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
test$a[3:4] <- NA
test$b[7] <- NA
lst <- adj_data_matplot(test[,1], test[,-1])

matplot(lst$x, lst$y, type = "b")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This solution clearly shows the interpolated values are different from the data, which is as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `na.interpolation` function from the `imputeTS` package:

```
test = data.frame(x = 1:10, a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
test$a[3:4] = NA
test$b[7] = NA
matplot(test[,-1])
matlines(test[,1], test[,-1])

library('imputeTS')

test <- na.interpolation(test, option = "linear")
matplot(test[,-1])
matlines(test[,1], test[,-1])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - that works fine. I forgot to mention that this is in a package and therefore I'd like to keep dependencies to a minimum. If you have any idea how to implement this without calling an external package, I would appreciate your insight.

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. I checked the source code of `na.interpolation` and it was actually easy to delete the part that calls functions from another package, so I just created the modified function and then there is no need to load the entire package.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I dunno -- as it is shown, the interpolated values are indistinguishable from the actual data. This is confusing or misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Had also the same issue today. In my context I was not permitted to interpolate. I am providing here a minimal, but sufficiently general working example of what I did. I hope it helps someone:

```
mymatplot <- function(data, main=NULL, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL,...){
    #graphical set up of the window
    plot.new()
    plot.window(xlim=c(1,ncol(data)), ylim=range(data, na.rm=TRUE))
    mtext(text = xlab,side = 1, line = 3)
    mtext(text = ylab,side = 2, line = 3)
    mtext(text = main,side = 3, line = 0)
    axis(1L)
    axis(2L)
    #plot the data
    for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
        nin.na <- !is.na(data[i,])
        lines(x=which(nin.na), y=data[i,nin.na], col = i,...)
    }
}
```

The core 'trick' is in `x=which(nin.na)`. It aligns the data points of the line consistently with the indices of the x axis.
The lines

```
plot.new()  
plot.window(xlim=c(1,ncol(data)), ylim=range(data, na.rm=TRUE))  
mtext(text = xlab,side = 1, line = 3)  
mtext(text = ylab,side = 2, line = 3)  
mtext(text = main,side = 3, line = 0)  
axis(1L)  
axis(2L)`
```

draw the graphical part of the window.
`range(data, na.rm=TRUE)` adapts the plot to a proper size being able to include all `data` points.
`mtext(...)` is used to label the axes and provides the main title. The axes themselves are drawn by the `axis(...)` command.
The following *for*-loop plots the data.
The function head of `mymatplot` provides the `...` argument for an optional passage of typical `plot` parameters as `lty`, `lwt`, `cex` etc. via . Those will be passed on to the `lines`.
At last word on the choice of colors - they are up to your flavor.